# Yii send email to multiple recipients

Tags: php, email, yii

hello im using yiimail here. i want to sent an email to multiple recipients

here is my code

```
$mailcc = explode(",", $model->EMAIL_RECEIVER);
$mail = new YiiMailMessage;
$mail->from = Yii::app()->params['senderEmail'];
// $mail->setTo(array($emailReceiver));
$mail->setTo($model->receiver1);
$mail->setCC($mailCC);
$mail->Subject = $model->SUBJECT;
$mail->Body = $model->BODY_EMAIL;
Yii::app()->mail->send($mail);
```

`$mailCC` get input value from user and `$model->receiver1` from database. if user input 2 other user for `$mailCC`, this only send to the first email, not both.

ex:

```
$model->receiver1=email1@mail.com
$mailCC = array("email2@mail.com", "email3@mail.com") //this is from user input
```

the email will only send to `email1@mail.com & email2@mail.com`

i've tried

```
    $mailcc = explode(",", $model->EMAIL_RECEIVER);
    $mail = new YiiMailMessage;
    $mail->from = Yii::app()->params['senderEmail'];
    // $mail->setTo(array($emailReceiver));
    $mail->setTo($model->receiver1);
    $mail->setCC(array($mailCC)); //this one with array
    $mail->Subject = $model->SUBJECT;
    $mail->Body = $model->BODY_EMAIL;
    Yii::app()->mail->send($mail);
```

but it return this error

`preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this problem done
here's my code

```
$mailcc = explode(",", $model->EMAIL_RECEIVER);
$mail = new YiiMailMessage;
$mail->from = Yii::app()->params['senderEmail'];
foreach($mailcc as $to){
    $mail->addTo(trim($to));
}
$mail->Subject = $model->SUBJECT;
$mail->Body = $model->BODY_EMAIL;
Yii::app()->mail->send($mail);
```

we should explode separator, loop recipients and change to addTo not setTo

thanks to u guys that have give some solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$mail->addCC($mailCC[0]);
$mail->addCC($mailCC[1]);
```

Hopefully it will work. Here is my complete running code

```
    $message = new YiiMailMessage;
    $message->view = 'registrationFollowup';

    //userModel is passed to the view
    $message->setBody(['userModel' => "test"], 'text/html');

    $message->setTo("xxxx@gmail.com");
    $message->addCC('yyyy@gmai.com');
    $message->addCC('zzz@gmai.com');
    $message->from = "pqr@gmail.com";
    $status = Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
    print_r($status); //print the number of recipient, which 3
```

Comment: i got this error when trying this code `Illegal offset type`

Comment: @Trainee please try now. I have add the running snippet

Comment: sry for late reply, if u're making that way it wont be a dynamical data, user will only can send 2 CC, not more than 2, thankyou anyway

Comment: i have try using this code `$emailReceiver = explode(",", $model->EMAIL_RECEIVER);
     $emailReceiver = array($emailReceiver);
     foreach($emailReceiver as $to){
      $mail->setTo($to);
     }` but still no success